# Conjugate Hyperbolas.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

[image]

What would be a good approach to tackle this problem. 
In a previous assignment I managed to show Pq=Pr. How do I show that this tangent intersects the conjugate hyperbola. Should I start by calculating the arbitrary tangent line and seeing how it intersects the conjugate and then show that Qq=Rr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An image:

***([Full Resolution Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flVKu.png))***
[image]

### The solution:

Well I like to work with:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Let point P be $(a\sec\theta,b\tan\theta)$ and the tangent and pair of asymptotes is:
$$\frac xa\sec\theta-\frac yb\tan\theta=1\\
\frac{x^2}{a^2}=\frac{y^2}{b^2}\implies y=\pm\frac bax$$
Now I am finding intersection:
$$\frac xa\sec\theta\pm\frac xa\tan\theta=1\implies x=a(\sec\theta\pm\tan\theta)\tag{q and r}$$
These two point correspond to $q$ and $r$:
$$q\equiv(a(\sec\theta+\tan\theta),b(\sec\theta+\tan\theta))\\
r\equiv(a(\sec\theta-\tan\theta),-b(\sec\theta-\tan\theta))$$
Now conjugate hyperbola is:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=-1$$ 
Again finding intersection:
$$x=a(sec\theta\pm\sqrt2\tan \theta)\tag{Q and R}$$
So Q and R are:
$$Q\equiv\left(a\left(\sec \theta+\sqrt2\tan \theta\right),b\left(\tan \theta+\sqrt{2}\sec \theta\right)\right)\\
R\equiv\left(a\left(\sec \theta-\sqrt{2}\tan \theta\right),b\left(\tan \theta-\sqrt{2}\sec \theta\right)\right)$$
Clearly $PQ=PR,Qq=Rr,qR=Qr$ using distance formula and the fact that $\alpha^2=(-\alpha)^2$.